Usage of the word 坊や
I was watching Dororo where the mother refers to her son, Hyakkimaru as 坊や (Boya). It sounds similar to "boy", so I assumed it is a Katakanized word until I found the Kanji word (which confirms it a Japanese word).
Since the story is set during the 1470s, the Japanese spoken must be old (Refer: Was "archaic Japanese" used to narrate historical anime series?) and this word was used then as well. So, I want to know if this word was prevalent from the starting where a mother would always refer to her child as 坊や or was any other word used?

Not a complete answer, but 坊主 was expanded to children during the Muromachi period as a generalization of the Monk's bald/close shorn head (since young boys hair was shorn similarly) (source: https://intojapanwaraku.com/rock/culture-rock/162627/). I've found a source of unknown reliability that says や was originally an interjection (like a sentence-end よ) (https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1341530598), so I 坊や is a shortening of 坊主+や. No idea what was used beforehand, but I imagine there were multiple options as parents are often calling their kids all kinds of things.

@YKa や as a suffix and や as a vocative particle should be distinguished. See my previous answer.

坊や was how you can address a small child. This is an old word and is usually heard in folk tales. While its usage is similar to "boy" when addressing him, its etymology is completely different.

坊 originally means "monk", but since there was a custom of shaving young boys' heads in the past, people used 坊 or 坊主 to refer to young boys as well. This custom remained until the late 20th century.
や is a diminutive suffix similar in purpose to "-ie" as in "doggie". There are also にいや (兄), ねえや (姉), ばあや (婆) and じいや (爺) used to address one's family members, but these are now almost obsolete, too.


Though it is a fairly common misunderstanding, names with ～や were not for addressing a true family member but only a fictive kin, or usually a servant of equivalent age and gender.
